# appium webdriver remoteserver UnreachableBrowserException

Tags: java, testing, mobile, automated-tests, appium

```
package basic_scenario;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Login_TG {

    WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() throws MalformedURLException
    {
        String apkpath="C:\\Users\\rgi-40\\android-sdks\\platform-tools\\AG.apk";
        File app=new File(apkpath);

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
        capabilities.setCapability("PlatformVersion", "6.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");  
        capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.AG.BaseClasses.Navigation.Activity.SplashScreenActivity");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.AG");
        capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions",true);
        capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", "60");
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Appium");
        //capabilities.setCapability("--session-override",true);

        try {
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:5038/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        } catch(UnreachableBrowserException e){
                System.out.println("cant find driver");
        }
    }
    @Test
    public void testLogin() throws Exception {

        WebElement login_element = driver.findElement(By.id(""));
        login_element.click();

        WebElement uname_element = driver.findElement(By.className(""));
        uname_element.sendKeys("");

        WebElement pwd_element = driver.findElement(By.id(""));
        pwd_element.sendKeys("");

        WebElement submit_element = driver.findElement(By.id(""));
        submit_element.click();
    }
    @AfterTest
    public void teardown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

windows 10 os
[check error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNejk.png)
Appium version = 1.6.1
Eclipse : neon 3.

First whole code is run perfect but after running multiple time test it shows
"unreachablebrowserexception"

i am not able to handle unreachable browser exception
if i am using androiddriver and appiumdriver , 
i am not able to getting the element inside `testLogin()` method.

Comment: That's not a standard URL.  Why port 5038?

Comment: its dummy port number for testing purpose ,and its local URL.Problem is not with this..problem is "i am not able to handle unreachable browser exception".

Comment: It can't reach the browser because it can't reach the Appium server.  The port number is key.  How do you have it configured in your Appium Server?

Comment: [Appium setup_config](http://prntscr.com/jov6fa)

Please check this screenshot

Comment: Can you post a link to your Appium server logs as well? There may be some important information regarding the exception you receive.

Comment: thank u all its solved i am just update the jar files

Comment: Can u plz elaborate..more about this.

Comment: ok..it is solved..